# Call function after currentUserSync - Async Await issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await, google-signin

I'm using [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin). My code is:

```
async _setupGoogleSignin() {
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true });
    await GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: '<from web>',
      offlineAccess: true
    });

    const user = await GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync()
      .then(this._someFunction(user));    // Is this correct? 
      console.log(user);        // this works. User is logged
  }

  catch(err) {
      console.log("Play services error", err.code, err.message);
    }
  }

_someFunction(user){

  console.log("ID: ",user.id)       // Error is thrown here

  this.setState({id: user.id});     // This is not set

}
```

With the `.then(this._someFunction(user));`, I want to pass the `user` to the function `_someFunction`.

The error is `Play services error undefined Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

I want to be able to call the function that sets the `user` when `GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync()` is completed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async..await` is mixed with regular promise code, and not in a good way.

`.then(this._someFunction(user))` is invalid, because `then` expects a function as an argument, and it receives `undefined`. Also, `user` is not defined at this point.

It should be

```
const user = await GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync();
this._someFunction(user);
```

This is exactly what `async..await` is for. To flatten the function and avoid `then`s when this is practical.